# Need help on PIL not showing image correctly

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
import numpy as np
import re
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("test_image.jpg")
hsv_img = image.convert('HSV')

x = np.array(hsv_img)
img_x = Image.fromarray(x, 'HSV')
img_x.show()

y = x*1.0
img_y = Image.fromarray(y, 'HSV')
img_y.show()
```

The first image show correctly while the second one failed and showing weird gray image. I don't get it. Both x and y are the same exact array. Can someone explain this?

Comment: are you missing a quotation mark in this -  Image.open("test_image.jpg).

Comment: Check the `dtype` of both arrays to see the problem, that is `print(x.dtype, y.dtype)`

Comment: Oh yes let me fix that. But that was not the problem. The code run well, just not showing image correctly.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Interestingly. Data types are uint8, float64 respectively. How do I fix this?

Comment: Ah got it. I need to multiply by 1 not 1.0 :/ Thanks @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 1):

As @MarkStchell pointed out. The x and y arrays data types are different. They are unit8 and float64 respectively. The fix would be to multiply by "1" instead of "1.0" or change the data type.